# How to remove specific line from the file

Tags: java, android, file, bufferedreader, fileoutputstream

I am trying to delete a specific line from a file, but when I run this, it returns me all the files, deleted. More specific i have a favorite button at a video fragment and i want when user press it ,to write the title of video in file (already done) and when unpress it to delete it....

my.java class is:

```
private void writeToFile(String g,Context context) {
    try {
        File file=new File("/data/data/com.holomedia.holomedia/config.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        if (!file.exists()) {outputStreamWriter.write(g);}
        outputStreamWriter.append("\n"+g +"\n");
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}

private void deleteToFile(String g,Context context) {
    try {
        File file=new File("/data/data/com.holomedia.holomedia/files/config.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        if (file.exists()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.equals(g) && !g.equals("\n")){
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            }
            br.close();
            outputStreamWriter.write(text.toString());
        }
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.favorite:
            if(showingFirst==true) {
                Context context = getActivity();
                CharSequence text = "Added to Favorites";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.heart_off);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                writeToFile(title,context);
                showingFirst=false;
            } else {
                Context context = getActivity();
                CharSequence text = "Deleted from Favorites";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                deleteToFile(title,context);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.heart_wh);
                showingFirst=true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.home:
            Intent k=new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: ");
            startActivity(k);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should try closing the BufferedReader BEFORE writing to the file, not after.

Comment: @BenjaminRacette i try it, but it doesnt work...

Comment: don't tell you tried, show. The code, if you please. Always and before being asked for it please.

Comment: @johnV are you saying final file is blank ?

Comment: ok then... edited done...!

Comment: @Ravi yes...exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, problem lies at below line of codes where you are trying to open file for Read and Write simultaneously

```
File file=new File("/data/data/com.holomedia.holomedia/files/config.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
if (file.exists()) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

Instead, I would suggest you to read your file completely and then at the end you should write to the file (overwrite).

```
try {
    File file=new File("/data/data/com.holomedia.holomedia/files/config.txt");

    if (file.exists()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.equals(g) && !g.equals("\n")){
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        }
        br.close();

        //start writing from here
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        outputStreamWriter.write(text.toString());
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } 
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: why it never satisfies? i want to write to text only if it isnt equal to the string it gets. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @johnV Are you still looking for solution ?

Comment: @johnV I probably know where the problem lies. Just wait for few min, iI will update my post

Comment: @johnV check my updated post. It will give you some hint and most probably it will work. let me know, if you still have issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

resets contents of the file (ie replaces it with empty file). I recommend you add logging and/or debug your code so you will have a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: i told before , i have a favorite button at a video fragment and i want when user press it to write the title of video in file (already done) and when unpress it to delete it....

Comment: How does this change the fact that you are clearing the contents of your file?